# problem with filling array data using pyhon oop inheritance

Tags: python, numpy, oop, inheritance

Im learning oop inheritance using python, but I have the fllowing when I call teh class solv the variable self.Y doesn`t recive the array data of the instance def fun(self, t, Y):
I need to fill the array self.Y with values of def fun(self, t, Y):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class System():
  
  def __init__(self):

    h = 0.5
    self.t = np.linspace(0, 20+h, int(20/h))
    self.x = np.zeros(len(self.t))
    self.x[0] = 5000
    self.y = np.zeros(len(self.t))
    self.y[0] = 0
    self.loop()
  
  def dxdt(self, x, y, t):

    return -0.1*x
  
  def dydt(self, x, y, t):

    return -0.1*x-0.2*y
  
  def loop(self):
    h = 0.5
    for i in range(len(self.t)-1):

      k1 = h*self.dxdt(self.x[i], self.y[i], self.t[i])
      l1 = h*self.dydt(self.x[i], self.y[i], self.t[i])
      k2 = h*self.dxdt(self.x[i]+k1*h/2, self.y[i]+l1*h/2, self.t[i]+h/2)
      l2 = h*self.dydt(self.x[i]+k1*h/2, self.y[i]+l1*h/2, self.t[i]+h/2) 
      k3 = h*self.dxdt(self.x[i]+k2*h/2, self.y[i]+l2*h/2, self.t[i]+h/2)
      l3 = h*self.dydt(self.x[i]+k2*h/2, self.y[i]+l2*h/2, self.t[i]+h/2)
      k4 = h*self.dxdt(self.x[i]+k3*h, self.y[i]+l3*h, self.t[i]+h)
      l4 = h*self.dydt(self.x[i]+k3*h, self.y[i]+l3*h, self.t[i]+h)
      self.x[i+1] = self.x[i] + 1/6*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
      self.y[i+1] = self.y[i] + 1/6*(l1 + 2*l2 + 2*l3 + l4)
    
class solv(System):
  def __init__(self):
    super(solv, self).__init__()
    self.Y = np.zeros(len(self.t))
    self.fun()
    
  def fun(self, t, Y):

    self.Y = np.append(self.Y, 5000 - 0.5*self.t**2)

  def dibu(self):
    plt.plot(self.t, self.Y, color='black')
    plt.show()

fn = solv()
fn.dibu()
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile because you're calling `self.loop()` in your `System` class ...

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of limited information you have provided, there are a few things in your code that do not make much sense:

- `solv.fun` is expected to receive `t` and `Y` but is called without any arguments.
- `System.loop` is not defined.

Since System.**init** defined `self.t` and `self.y` you will have access to those attributes in `solv.func`. Therefore you can do something like this:

```
class System():
    def __init__(self):
        h = 0.5
        self.t = np.linspace(0, 20+h, int(20/h))
        self.x = np.zeros(len(self.t))
        self.x[0] = 5000
        self.y = np.zeros(len(self.t))
        self.y[0] = 0

class solv(System):
    def __init__(self):
        super(solv, self).__init__()
        self.fun()
    
    def fun(self):
        self.Y = 5000 - 0.5*self.t**2 # <- this is just an example
                                      # since you plot self.t, self.Y
                                      # they must have the same length

    def dibu(self):
        plt.plot(self.t, self.Y, color='black')
        plt.show()

fn = solv()
fn.dibu()
```

Comment: Thanks, but the variable self.y called in the instance master System is different to the vatiable self.Y I need to fill the array self.Y with value of  def fun(self):
        self.Y = 5000 - 0.5*self.t**2

Comment: @FabianZamora it is unclear to me what's the relation between `self.y` and `self.Y` and how you expect `self.t` to have the same length as `self.Y`...

Comment: self.y is the numeral solution and self.Y is the analytical solution, self.t is array axis x. I need tha in the class solv, the values of the  analytical solution 5000 - 0.5*self.t**2 its store in array self.Y